# how to fetch data from 3 different table in laravel using advance join

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have 3 table

This is my first table cart_items .
[image: Cart table]

This is my second table ecomm_products.
[image: ecomm]

This is my Third table ecomm_sellers.
[image]

```
$result = DB::table('cart_items')
    ->join('ecomm_products','ecomm_sellers',function($join){
      $join->on('ecomm_products.id','=','cart_items.product_id')->where('cart_items.order_id','=',1);
      $join->on('ecomm_products.seller_id','=','ecomm_sellers.id');
    })
    ->where('cart_items.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
    ->select('ecomm_products.product_name','ecomm_products.showcase_image','ecomm_products.selling_price','cart_items.quantity','cart_items.id')
    ->get();
```

But I am getting an error ⛔⛔⛔

```
strtolower(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, Closure given
```

When I have not included 3 tables (ecomm_sellers) till the query is running good but when I add it sends me some errors.

The question is: Why I am getting this error and why this query is not working, What else I can add so that my query working fine.

Comment: i strongly think that the problem is somewhere else, can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot join two tables in by passing the table names as arguments to `join`. If you check the API documentation of the [join method](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_join) you can see that its signature is:

`$this join(string $table, Closure|string $first, string|null $operator = null, string|null $second = null, string $type = 'inner', bool $where = false)`

so you can only join two tables at a time and if you want to join more than two tables you chain another call to the `join` method.

try this:

```php
$result = DB::table('cart_items')
    ->join('ecomm_products', 'ecomm_products.id', '=', 'cart_items.product_id')
    ->join('ecomm_sellers' , 'ecomm_products.seller_id', '=', 'ecomm_sellers.id')
    ->where('cart_items.order_id', '=', 1)
    ->where('cart_items.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->select([
        'ecomm_products.product_name',
        'ecomm_products.showcase_image',
        'ecomm_products.selling_price',
        'cart_items.quantity',
        'cart_items.id'
    ])
    ->get();
```

You can find examples for Laravel query builder joins [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins)

Comment: Thanks bro . for the code it started working.

Comment: If it is possible for you then please tell me what's wrong with my code, and how did you remove it... It will help me a lot in the future.?

Comment: Glad I could help. I added more details to the answer. I hope it's clearer now